# msmdpump to SSAS

Tags: windows, http, windows-7, ssas, iis-7.5

I have got msmdpump.dll set up on a windows 7 machine pointing to an SSAS instance on another server and every request I send is being logged in the event viewer with the following error.

Event ID:

> 10

Qualifiers:

> 16653

Message:

> Message-handling subsystem: The message manager for the default locale cannot be found. The locale will be changed to US English

I have another msmdpump set up on that local machine as well which works perfectly but this is on windows 2003.

Full XML message

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="MSOLAP ISAPI Extension: \\?\c:\inetpub\wwwroot\olap\msmdpump.dll" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="16653">10</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>269</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-08-31T10:47:11.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>5174</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>test.local</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
  <Data>Message-handling subsystem: The message manager for the default locale cannot be found. The locale will be changed to US English.</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

EDIT:
Please note additionally that this call is through another data pump which can successfully connect to the SSAS instance.

EDIT2: 
The error message looks to be coming from SSAS - so the request IS getting there. But it is failing on the user. Would I not appear coming through as the same user as the other data pump? Both data pumps are using Anonymous Authentication.

Actually any data on how the msmdpump.dll works would be great. All I've found is how to set it up not actually how it works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

msmdpump translates a http request into a TCP/IP request to SSAS. I do not believe that trying to point one instance of msmdpump to another will work.

Comment: Thanks. This explains it. I never got it sorted.